# How to Fetch A Record If Shipping And billing Address are Different

Tags: mysql, join, query

Show New Orders with Address If shipping and billing are different. I am stuck with this query. Can someone guide me a bit. Thanks
[image]

Comment: Do you want to always show both addresses?  Shahid shows how.  Further note that if you store the same id into `ShippingAddressId` and `BillingAddressId`, you get the same address without wasting space.  (But it could be tricky to update one without also changing the other.)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  t.TripId_PK, ls.name StartLocationName, le.name EndLocationName
FROM    trips t
JOIN    locations ls
ON      ls.LocationId_PK = t.StartLocationId_FK
JOIN    locations le
ON      le.LocationId_PK = t.EndLocationId_FK
```